# How come console prints only 1 unique address of integer variable when using address-of operator?

Tags: c++, memory

I am a university student currently studying computer science and programming and while reading chapter 2 of c++ primer by Stanley B. Lippmann a question popped up into my mind and that is, if computer memory is divided into tiny storage locations called Bytes (8 bits) and each Byte of memory is assigned a unique address, and an integer variable uses up 4 Bytes of memory, shouldn't my console, when using the address-of operator print out 4 unique addresses instead of 1?

I doubt that the textbook is incorrect and that their is a flaw in my understanding of computer memory. As a result, I would like a positive clarification of this question I am facing. Thanks in advance people :)

Comment: I think I can put it this way: All four bytes are allocated as one `block of memory` for your integer, where each block has a unique address.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Extending on @FirstStep's comment, the location of the first byte and its length are all that is required to know everything you need to know. The real pain comes later with pointers to arrays where you might not know the length.

Comment: This [link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html) provides a very good explanation.

Comment: Um... Address-of operator does not print anything. Neither 1 address, nor 4. If you are printing something in your program, it is *you* who are doing this, using some other tools. If you print 1 address - you get 1 address, if you print 4 - you get 4, if you print 100 addresses - you get 100 addresses. But from what you posted so far it is completely unclear what you are printing and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes an integer type requires four bytes. **All** four bytes are allocated as **one** `block of memory` for your integer, where each block has a unique address. This unique address is simply the first byte's address of the `block`.

Answer (score 6):

> shouldn't my console, when using the address-of operator print out 4 unique addresses instead of 1?

No.

The address of an object is the address of its starting byte. A 4-byte `int` has a unique address, the address of its first byte, but it occupies the next three bytes as well. Those next three bytes have different addresses, but they are not the address of the `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Each *variable* is located in memory somewhere, so each *variable* gets an address you can get with the address-of operator.

That each byte in a multi-byte variable also have their addresses doesn't matter, the address-of operator gives you a pointer to the *variable*.

Some "graphics" to hopefully explain it...

Lets say we have an `int` variable named `i`, and that the type `int` takes four bytes (32 bits, this is the usual for `int`). Then you have something like

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Some place is reserved for the four bytes, where doesn't matter the compiler will handle all that for you.

Now if you use the address-of operator to get a *pointer* to the variable `i` i.e. you do `&i`, then you have something like

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
^
|
&i
```

The expression `&i` points to the memory position where the byte-sequence of the variable *begins*. It can't possible give you multiple pointers, one for each byte, that's really impossible, and not needed as well.